# Помогите найти ошибку и решить пж

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

когда я пишу `лео команды` то бот отвечает типы команд и перечесляет какие есть и когда я пишу `лео команды основные` то бот пишет не основные команды а обычные типы команд,как исправить ошибку?

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.obj['message']['text'].lower().startswith('лео'):
        print(str(event.obj['message']['from_id']) + '[' + str(event.obj['message']['peer_id']) + ']:' +
              event.obj['message']['text'])

        def message_send(message='', id=event.obj['message']['peer_id'], att='', vk=vk, event=event):
            vk.messages.send(peer_id=id, message=message, random_id=random.randint(0, 2 ** 64), attachment=att)
        def msg():
            msg = event.obj['message']['text'].split()
            del msg[0]
            text = ' '.join(msg)
            return text
        def name(vk=vk):
            get_info = vk.users.get(user_ids=event.obj['message']['from_id'])
            name = '[id' + str(event.obj['message']['from_id']) + '|' + get_info[0]['first_name'] + ' ' + get_info[0][
                'last_name'] + ']'
            return name

        if event.obj['message']['text'].lower().startswith("лео команды"): #Основные команды, список
            message_send(f"Тут типы команд\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"")

        elif event.obj['message']['text'].lower().startswith == "лео команды основные":
            message_send(f"Тут основные команды\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"")


        else:
            vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj['message']['peer_id'], message='Команда не найдена!',
                                random_id=random.randint(0, 2 ** 64)) #Если команды нету то будет выдовать ошибку
```

Comment: Крч, пж... Что вы делаете с уймой освободившегося времени?

Comment: Можно поменять startswith на обычное сравнение) Во втором случае, вы даже не вызвали функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте `if` и `elif` поменять местами:

```
        if event.obj['message']['text'].lower().startswith("лео команды основные"): #Основные команды, список
            message_send(f"Тут типы команд\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"")

        elif event.obj['message']['text'].lower().startswith("лео команды"):
            message_send(f"Тут основные команды\n"
                         f"\n"
                         f"")
```